# Delete a specific character in txt

Tags: python, awk, sed

Imagine that I've the next txt format:

```
'20201': "a" ,
'20202': "e" ,
'20203': "i" ,
'20204': "o" ,
'20205': "u" ,
'20207': "ae" ,
'20209': "ai" ,
'20210': "ao"
```

And I want to erase the four digit when it's a 0. So the expected output is:

```
'2021': "a" ,
'2022': "e" ,
'2023': "i" ,
'2024': "o" ,
'2025': "u" ,
'2027': "ae" ,
'2029': "ai" ,
'20210': "ao"
```

I'm thinking about this:

````
awk -i inplace  ' { for ( i = 1; i <= NF; ++i ) {

    if ( $i == '0')
        r = 1

    
    }
  }}
1 ' example.txt ```
````

Comment: Don't use `-i inplace` (or even show it in your question) while you're working on a solution. Just let the output display to stdout til you get it right.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With `awk` could you please try following, written and tested with shown samples in GNU `awk`.

Without field separator try:

```
awk 'substr($0,5,1)==0{ $0=substr($0,1,4) substr($0,6) } 1'  Input_file
```

OR with field separator try following: To deal with only 1st field here specifically.

```
awk '
BEGIN{
  FS=OFS=":"
}
substr($1,5,1)==0{
  $1=substr($1,1,4) substr($1,6)
}
1
'  Input_file
```

To save output into Input_file itself append  `> temp && mv temp Input_file` once you are happy with above command's output.

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
awk '                             ##Starting awk program from here.
BEGIN{                            ##Starting BEGIN section of this program from here.
  FS=OFS=":"                      ##Setting FS and OFS as colon here.
}
substr($1,5,1)==0{                ##Checking condition if 5th character is 0 then do following.
  $1=substr($1,1,4) substr($1,6)  ##Setting sub string of 1st 4 characters then mentioning characters from 6th character to last of 1st field here.
}
1                                 ##1 will print current line.
' Input_file                      ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

Comment: It´s not modifying anything

Comment: @Max, Yeah, I have mentioned in answer. "To save output into Input_file itself append ` > temp && mv temp Input_file` once you are happy with above command's output."

Answer (score 4):

For a terse GNU `sed` solution, this works:

```
sed "s/^\(....\)0/\1/" example.txt
```

Here, we just match the first 5 characters -- with the first 4 being free & the 5th being a zero. For any matches, we replace the first 5 characters with only the first 4 characters.

If you want to *modify* the file inplace, you can use sed's `-i` option:

```
sed "s/^\(....\)0/\1/" -i example.txt
```

(Note `-i` will work on many, but not all, systems; see workarounds [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5694228/sed-in-place-flag-that-works-both-on-mac-bsd-and-linux))

Comment: The answer above answers the question succinctly but perhaps `sed -E 's/^(.{4})0/\1/' file` although not shorter has more mileage.

Comment: I am not seeing what makes this SED GNU specific?

Answer (score 2):

If my **substring** is a positive number, remove the fourth digit if it is zero:

```
sed -e 's/\([0-9][0-9][0-9]\)0/\1/g' file
```

If my **word** is a positive number, remove the fourth digit if it is zero:

```
sed -e 's/\b\([0-9][0-9][0-9]\)0\([0-9]*\)\b/\1\2/g' file
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use `python` as a tagged option, then consider working with `pandas.read_csv` function along with `str.split` and `str.replace` methods, and then applying `str.join` method combining each splitted pieces for each derived lines while writing into the original file such as

```
import pandas as pd

sss=[]
with open('myfile.txt','r') as f_in:
        data = pd.read_csv(f_in,header=None)        
        for line in data[0]:
            s=line.split()
            j=0
            ss=""
            for i in s[0]:
                j+=1
                if j==5: # including the first quote(')
                    if i!='0':
                        ss+=i
                else:
                    ss+=i

            sss.append(line.replace(s[0],ss))                 
j=0
ss=""
with open('myfile.txt','w') as f_out:
    for line in sss:
        j+=1
        ss=''.join(str(line))
        if j==len(sss):
            f_out.write(ss+'\n')
        else:
            f_out.write(ss+',\n')
```

Answer (score 0):

You might harness GNU `AWK` [gensub](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html) for that following way, let `file.txt` content
be

```
'20201': "a" ,
'20202': "e" ,
'20203': "i" ,
'20204': "o" ,
'20205': "u" ,
'20207': "ae" ,
'20209': "ai" ,
'20210': "ao"
```

then

```
awk '{print gensub(/^(....)0/,"\\1",1)}' file.txt
```

output

```
'2021': "a" ,
'2022': "e" ,
'2023': "i" ,
'2024': "o" ,
'2025': "u" ,
'2027': "ae" ,
'2029': "ai" ,
'20210': "ao"
```

Explanation: I used gensub's *ability to specify components of a regexp in the replacement text* to instruct to replace (first 4 characters followed by zero) using (these first 4 characters). We need to get 4 first characters, due to leading ' which means 4th digit is 5th character.