# sed regular expression error \1 not defined in the RE

Tags: macos, sed

I am trying to replace test004.abc.com with eh6.test004.abc.com.

The csv file has rows

```
scheme,host,Username,Password
https,test003.abc.com,test003_0021,abc1!
https,test046.abc.com,test046_015,abc1!
....
```

I have this sed which I am trying

```
sed -i -E "s/(https,)(test\d{3}\.abc\.com,test\d{3}_\d{3,},abc\!)/\1eh6.\2/g"  EH6_Random.csv
```

but its throwing error

```
sed: 1: "s/(https,)(test\d{3 ...": \1 not defined in the RE
```

since I am using -E there shouldn't be need of escaping the regular expression fo group brackets (). I have tried this as well and removed -E , but it still didnt work.

Comment: `\d` is not supported in `ERE`. Just use `[0-9]`

Comment: Tried with [0-9] but still didnt work ```sed -i -E "s/(https,)(test[0-9]{3}.abc.com,test[0-9]{3}_[0-9]{3,},abc1\!)/\1eh6.\2/"  EH6_Random.csv                sed: 1: "s/(https,)(test[0-9 ...": \1 not defined in the RE. ```

Comment: Tried by simplifying RE

``` sed -i -E "s/(https,)(test.*)/\1eh6.\2/"  EH6_Random.csv ```

but the same error

```ed: 1: "s/(https,)(test.*)/ ...": \1 not defined in the RE```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're dealing with CSV data, I would suggest better tool `awk` for this.

````sh
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} $2 ~ /^test[0-9]{3}\.abc\.com$/ {$2 = "eh6." $2} 1' file

scheme,host,Username,Password
https,eh6.test003.abc.com,test003_0021,abc1!
https,eh6.test046.abc.com,test046_015,abc1!```
````

Comment: I have corrected my comments above. I need to prefix second column with ***eh6.***
 test004.abc.com with eh6.test004.abc.com.
test046.abc.com with eh6.test046.abc.com 

and so on.

Could you please update your answer accordingly ?

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 's/\<test[0-9]\{3\}\.abc\.com/eh6.test.abc.com/' file
```

Replace `testnnn.abc.com` with `eh6.test.abc.com` where test begins on a word boundary and  `nnn` is a 3 digit number.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the version of `sed` that macOS uses has different syntax for the `-i` option than the GNU version, which is causing a chain reaction of misinterpretation.

The `-i` option tells `sed` to modify the file "in-place", and takes an optional argument that's used as a suffix to store the original file as a backup. If you don't want a backup, you pass the empty string as the backup suffix. The problem is *how* you pass that empty string. With GNU `sed`, the suffix must be directly attached to the `-i` option (like `sed -i.bkp ...`), so just using `-i` with nothing after it works. But the version macOS uses allows the suffix to be passed as a separate "word" (like `sed -i .bkp ...`), so to specify no backup you need to pass an explicit empty string (like `sed -i '' ...`).

As a result, when you use `sed -i -E ...` on macOS, it interprets `-E` as a suffix to use on a backup file, *doesn't* interpret it as meaning "use extended regex syntax", and therefore misparses the regular expression as containing no capture groups.

Solution: either pass an explicit null suffix (`sed -i '' -E ...`) or, if you want it to be compatible with GNU `sed`, pass an actual backup suffix (and directly attach it so GNU doesn't get confused: `sed -i.bkp -E ...`). There is no way to portably use `sed -i` without a backup (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5694228/sed-in-place-flag-that-works-both-on-mac-bsd-and-linux)).

Also, as anubhava pointed out in the comments, `\d` isn't supported here, so use `[0-9]` instead.

Comment: Thank you, this was the solution to my problem!