# Why can't I execute $ bundle exec rake secret? The error "bad interpreter: No such file or directory" occured

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bash, macos, heroku, sed

My ruby ​​version is 2.3.0, my mysql version is 8.0.23, my mysql2 version is 0.5.3, my rails version is 5.0.7.2, and my Xcode version is 12.5.

I use macOS Big Sur(version 11.4) and the text editor "Atom".

I'm planning to release my Rails application with the URL of HEROKU(example. https://[My APP Name].herokuapp.com).

I ran the following command.

```
$ heroku open
```

The following error occured.

```
An unhandled lowlevel error occurred. The application logs may have details.
```

I ran the following command.

```
$ heroku logs

#<RuntimeError: Missing
 `secret_key_base` for 'production' environment, set this value in `
config/secrets.yml`>
```

My config/secrets.yml file is something like belows.

```
production:
  secret_key_base: <%= ENV["SECRET_KEY_BASE"] %>
```

I edited my config/secrets.yml file as below.

```
production:
  secret_key_base: <%= ENV["secret_key_base"] %>
```

I deleted two environment variables as below with this command: `$ heroku config:unset [ENVIRONMENT VARIABLE NAME]`.

```
$ heroku config:unset DATABASE_USERNAME=****
```

```
$ heroku config:unset DATABASE_PASSWORD=GENERATED_CODE
```

I deleted the environment variable `SECRET_KEY_BASE` in the vim editor of `/etc/profile` , using the following command.

```
$ vi /etc/profile
```

I saved the vim editor of `/etc/profile` to end it with the two below commands.

```
:w !sudo tee %
```

```
:q!
```

I deleted the environment variable `SECRET_KEY_BASE`, using the following command.

```
$ vi ~/.bash_profile
```

I saved `.bash_profile` ,using <kbd>Esc</kbd> and then "`:x`" and <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

I ran the following command.

```
$ bundle exec rake secret

bash: /usr/local/bin/bundle: /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/
usr/bin/ruby: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

I ran the following command.

```
$ sed -i 's/\r//' usr/local/bin/bundle

sed: 1: "usr/local/bin/bundle": invalid command code u
```

I ran the following command.

```
$ /usr/local/bin/bundle

bash: /usr/local/bin/bundle: /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/
usr/bin/ruby: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

Below are the output of `gem env`, `which bundle` and `which ruby`.

```
$ gem env

RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 3.0.3
  - RUBY VERSION: 2.6.3 (2019-04-16 patchlevel 62) [universal.x86_64-darwin20]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0
  - USER INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /Users/****/.gem/ruby/2.6.0
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/bin/
ruby
  - GIT EXECUTABLE: /usr/local/bin/git
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /usr/local/bin

  - SPEC CACHE DIRECTORY: /Users/****/.gem/specs
  - SYSTEM CONFIGURATION DIRECTORY: /Library/Ruby/Site
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - universal-darwin-20
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0
     - /Users/****/.gem/ruby/2.6.0
     - /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.
0
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - https://rubygems.org/
  - SHELL PATH:
     - /usr/local/bin
     - /usr/bin
     - /bin
     - /usr/sbin
     - /sbin
     - /Users/****/.rbenv/shims
```

```
$ which bundle

/usr/local/bin/bundle
```

```
$ which ruby

/usr/bin/ruby
```

I installed the ruby version "2.3.0" as below ,because bundle seems to call "2.3".

```
$ rbenv install 2.3.0

Downloading openssl-1.0.2u.tar.gz...
-> https://****
Installing openssl-1.0.2u...
Installed openssl-1.0.2u to /Users/****/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0

Downloading ruby-2.3.0.tar.bz2...

-> https://****
Installing ruby-2.3.0...

WARNING: ruby-2.3.0 is past its end of life and is now unsupported.
It no longer receives bug fixes or critical security updates.

ruby-build: using readline from homebrew
Installed ruby-2.3.0 to /Users/****/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0
```

I verified that the ruby version "2.3.0" is installed and the current ruby version is "2.3.0".

```
$ rbenv local 2.3.0
```

```
$ rbenv rehash
```

```
$ rbenv versions
  
  system
* 2.3.0
```

```
$ rbenv global 2.3.0
```

```
$ rbenv rehash
```

```
$ rbenv versions

  system
* 2.3.0
```

But the ruby current version is "2.6.3" when used the below command.

```
$ ruby -v

ruby 2.6.3p62 (2019-04-16 revision 67580) [universal.x86_64-darwin20]
```

```
$ gem env

RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 3.0.3
  - RUBY VERSION: 2.6.3 (2019-04-16 patchlevel 62) [universal.x86_64-darwin20]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0
  - USER INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /Users/****/.gem/ruby/2.6.0

  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/bin/ruby
  - GIT EXECUTABLE: /usr/local/bin/git
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /usr/local/bin
  - SPEC CACHE DIRECTORY: /Users/****/.gem/specs
  - SYSTEM CONFIGURATION DIRECTORY: /Library/Ruby/Site
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - universal-darwin-20
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0
     - /Users/****/.gem/ruby/2.6.0
     - /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - https://rubygems.org/
  - SHELL PATH:
     - /usr/local/bin
     - /usr/bin
     - /bin
     - /usr/sbin
     - /sbin
     - /Users/****/.rbenv/shims
```

I ran the following command.

```
$ bundle exec rake secret

bash: /usr/local/bin/bundle: /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/
usr/bin/ruby: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

Why can't I execute `$ bundle exec rake secret`? And why are there the multiple current ruby versions "2.3.0","2.6.3"?

The error "`bad interpreter: No such file or directory`" occured.

Comment: Can you share the output of `gem env`, `which bundle` and `which ruby` please ?

Comment: It looks like you're trying to use Linux-style `sed` commands on macOS, which is just different enough to be confusing. First, you need to use an explicit empty arg after `-i` (that is `sed -i '' ...`; see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5694228)), and also it won't interpret `\r` as a carriage return. Also, I'd take a look at `/usr/local/bin/bundle` (note: the leading `/` is *required* for that path to work) and see what it actually contains before blindly trying to fix it. What is its actual shebang line? Does it contain carriage returns?

Comment: @Marchan4 : The error message looks like a missing slash in a #! line, or you have a relative directory in your PATH. What is the first line of `/usr/bin/bundle` and the value of $PATH?

Comment: You'll want to follow the previous advice and see what `which bundle` and `which ruby` returns, but it looks like you may not be using a ruby version manager. Highly suggested for macOS (rvm, rbenv, chruby, or asdf are all fine)