# Replace version inside YAML file

Tags: ubuntu, sed, gitlab

I have this YAML file:

```
openapi: 3.0.0
info:
  title: Test
  description: >-
    This is the official REST API documentation for all available routes
    provided by the **Test** plugin.
  version: 2.0.0
servers:
  - url: https://entwicklungsumgebung
components:
  securitySchemes:
    basicAuth:
      type: http
```

Inside my CI pipeline, I'm trying to modify the version at line 7. At the middle of the file, there are multiple keys named `test_version` or `prod_version` which should not be replaced. For this, I've written this `sed` command:

```
sed -i '' 's/^version: .*/version: 3.0.0/' test.yml
```

Initially, I've not used `^` after `s/` but this matched also everything before version. Now, nothing gets replaced. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to preserve the whitespace, so you either have to match the entire line and use a capture group:

```bash
sed -i '' 's/^\([[:blank:]]*version:\) .*/\1 3.0.0/' test.yml
```

Or you could match only `version`, with the risk of matching where it shouldn't:

```bash
sed -i '' 's/\(version:\) .*/\1 3.0.0/' test.yml
```

A more robust solution would be to use a tool what can parse YAML, such as [yq](https://github.com/mikefarah/yq):

```bash
yq -i '.info.version = "3.0.0"' test.yml
```

Comment: Solution 1 seems to match also my other versions like: `new_version`, `installed_version`

Comment: @Mr.Jo I don't see how that's possible, the regular expression is anchored at the line start and allows only blanks before `version`. Did you skip the `^`?

Comment: No, I executed it 1:1. Maybe it's because I'm testing on a MacBook?

Comment: If I execute it on my Ubuntu 18.4 (I know, EOL comes) I'm getting another error: `sed: can't read s/^\([[:blank:]]*version:\) .*/\1 20.0.0/: No such file or directory` The file is directly inside the execution path of the sed command!

Comment: If I remove the `''` after the`sed` command on Ubuntu, everything works! Also, the correct version gets changed. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Mr.Jo Oh, you're on Linux, then yes, the `''` are not required there, but they are required for macOS sed. This comes down to basically [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5694228/3266847).

Comment: And [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24276470/3266847) is an excellent overview of all the differences.

Answer (score 1):

I would use a find ..  To find all your YML files .. Then, there is no need for the `^` in your regex.  I also use the -i flag for suffixing as a precaution, and `/g` for "global" just in case `version:` is mentioned more than one time in the file --

**edit** Also leave the white space before  `version` -- in the replacement to preserve the indention

```
find ./ -name '*.yml' -exec sed -i "s/ version: .*/ version: 3.0.0/g" {} \;
```

So this file BEFORE:

```
openapi: 3.0.0
info:
  title: Test
  description: >-
    This is the official REST API documentation for all available routes
    provided by the **Test** plugin.
  test_version: 5.2.2
  prod_version: 4.3.3
 version: 2.0.0
servers:
  - url: https://entwicklungsumgebung
components:
  securitySchemes:
    basicAuth:
      type: http
```

OUTPUT:

```
openapi: 3.0.0
info:
  title: Test
  description: >-
    This is the official REST API documentation for all available routes
    provided by the **Test** plugin.
  test_version: 5.2.2
  prod_version: 4.3.3
 version: 3.0.0
servers:
  - url: https://entwicklungsumgebung
components:
  securitySchemes:
    basicAuth:
      type: http
```

Comment: I'm getting an error: `find ./ -name 'test.yml' -exec sed -i "s/ version: .*/ version: 3.0.0/g" {} \;
sed: 1: ".//test.yml": invalid command code .`

Comment: Depending on your version of `sed` .. Try it without the `-i` flag ..  --  Tested on Ubuntu 20.04 with the exact contents above copied and pasted.

Comment: You can also try JUST the `sed` command `sed -i "s/ version: .*/ version: 3.0.0/g" test.yml` -- Also tested and functioning ..

Comment: I was testing locally on my Mac. Maybe it’s different there. I’ll test on my Ubuntu target server in 1 1/2 hours and let you know the results! Maybe there is something different at macOS

Comment: Mac `sed` is slightly different --  I am not versed .. But I know that there are slight syntactical differences. -- including the `-s` and `-i` flags.  My solution will work on your production machine.

Comment: I'm unable to test it inside my GitLab CI/CD Pipeline because if I copy it into my YAML CI file, my IDE says the following and GitLab execution fails: `Schema validation: Incompatible types. Required one of: array, string. Actual: object. `

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251907/discussion-between-mr-jo-and-zak).

Comment: The above answer works now for me but I love your approach and would like to test it as well! The find can be useful for different cases. Let's try to get it running as well.

Comment: @Mr.Jo see chat