# Find and sed together fail in macOS

Tags: macos, sed, find

This command finds files if I remove from `exec` onwards.

```bash
find src -name "*.tsx" -o -name "*.ts" -exec sed -i "" "s/LayerSelector/LayerRenderer/g" {} \;
```

The `LayerSelector` is indeed in most of those files, and the `-i` should replace in place.

However, nothing happens. No changes in files, no message.

What is wrong with this simple command ?

---

However, this works fine:

```
sed -i "" "s/LayerSelector/LayerRenderer/g" src/**/*.tsx
```

Comment: Why the `""` ?   I'd think you should remove it.

Comment: @stevesliva That's requited by bsd (/macOS) version of `sed` if you want to pass `-i` without a backup file extension; see ["sed in-place flag that works both on Mac (BSD) and Linux"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5694228/sed-in-place-flag-that-works-both-on-mac-bsd-and-linux).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing parentheses around the `-o` clause:

```
find src \( -name "*.tsx" -o -name "*.ts" \) -exec sed -i "" "s/LayerSelector/LayerRenderer/g" {} \;
```

Without the parentheses, due to operator precedence, this:

```
find src -name "*.tsx" -o -name "*.ts" -exec sed -i "" "s/LayerSelector/LayerRenderer/g" {} \;
```

is the same as this (which is probably not what you want, because it does nothing to `"*.tsx"` files):

```
find src \( -name "*.tsx" \) -o \( -name "*.ts" -exec sed -i "" "s/LayerSelector/LayerRenderer/g" {} \; \)
```

**See also:**

- [`find` with multiple `-name` and `-exec` executes only the last matches of `-name` - Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/102191/find-with-multiple-name-and-exec-executes-only-the-last-matches-of-nam)
- [Operator precedence in a find command? - Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/276574/operator-precedence-in-a-find-command)