# Search and replace or append a value if not exist in a file in Bash in one line (for Linux and MacOS)

Tags: linux, bash, sed

I have a file like that:

```bash
one_variable=/tmp
version=16.0
another_variable=jack
```

and I'm trying to search and replace the value of `version` if it exists or append `version=newvalue` if it doesn't.

At the moment I'm using this one-line sed command which works great on Linux. It replaces the value of `version` with `$version_selected` or appends `version=` with the new value.

```bash
# sed -i'' -e "/^version=/{h;s/=.*/=$version_selected/};\${x;/^$/{s//version=$version_selected/;H};x}" infile
```

However, on MacOS this thrown an error:

```bash
sed: 1: "/^version=/{h;s/=. ...": bad flag in substitute command: '}'
```

How can I make it work on both Linux and MacOS in one line? Maybe can `awk` do the same without any issues? Or something else? I don't work use `gsed`!

Comment: `-i''` is **exactly** the same as `-i` alone, so on MacOS sed things you're running `-i -e`, telling it to use `-e` as a file extension. For the `''` to make any difference, you need a space between the `-i` and the `''`.

Comment: Maybe adding a semicolon before `}`; `sed -e '/^version=/{h;s/=.*/=$version_selected/;};...`

Comment: To position *version* line at 2nd when not exist: Maybe this could do something: `sed -e '1{h;d;};H;$!d;${x;s/\(\nversion[[:space:]]*=[[:space:]]*\)[^\n]*\n/\142\n/;ta;s/^\([^\n]*\n[^\n]*\n\)/\1version\o11= 42\n/;:a;}' -i ''` (or whthout the *spaces* `\o11``[[:space:]]*` and ` `...)

Comment: Using `sed -i` without a backup file is not portable between the macOS (BSD) and Linux (GNU) versions of `sed`, but if creating a backup file is ok, `sed -i.bak` will work with both (see ["sed in-place flag that works both on Mac (BSD) and Linux"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5694228/sed-in-place-flag-that-works-both-on-mac-bsd-and-linux)).

Comment: @F.Hauri-GiveUpGitHub slightly better result using `;` like this: `sed -i'' -e "/^version=/{h;s/=.*/=$version_selected/;};\${x;/^$/{s//version=$version_selected/;H;};x;}" infile`. No more errors and now replacement works on both Linux and MacOS but appending (if doens't exist) doesn't anymore.

Comment: @GordonDavisson Doing this `sed -i.bak "/^version=/{h;s/=.*/=$version_selected/;};\${x;/^$/{s//version=$version_selected/g;H;};x;}" infile` works fine on MacOS while in Linux replacement works but appending doesn't.

Comment: @KaMZaTa My purpose was to place *`version`* at 2nd line of config file if they are not present! Your version just add them at end if not found!

Comment: @F.Hauri-GiveUpGitHub that's not necessary for my purpose. However, I tried and sadly didn't work: `sed: 2: "1{h;d;};H;$!d;${x;s/\(\ ...": unexpected EOF (pending }'s)` (on MacOS)

Answer (score 0):

Using this small bash script I am demonstrating .. Replace the entire line by using wildcards `.*` Then just replace it with `version=$version_selected`

Also I find it easier just to `grep` whether the file contains the string you are looking for -- Append then exit the process if it's the case, else replace with selected version.

**version.txt**

```
one_variable=/tmp
version=16.0
another_variable=jack
```

**version.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash

file=version.txt
version_selected=17.56

#Check to see if exists .. If not append
if ! grep -q "version=" "$file"; then
  echo "version=$version_selected" >> $file;
  exit 1;
fi

sed -i "s/version.*/version=$version_selected/g" "$file"
```

Your replaced contents in **version.txt** should be:

```
one_variable=/tmp
version=17.56
another_variable=jack
```

Comment: This doesn't handle the "or append if not existing" requirement.

Comment: (also, I strongly advise against using `bash -e` -- see [BashFAQ #105](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105), skipping the story for the exercises below if in a hurry).

Comment: @Charles -- Thanks for the correction on the `-e` flag .. I have addressed the "append if not exists" portion as well.

Comment: BTW, if you leave off the `1` from the `exit 1` and make it just `exit`, the exit status will be that of the `echo` command (as the default behavior is `echo "$?"`). Probably that's what you want -- successfully appending a value is completing the script's purpose, after all; whereas if the open fails, it's correct to pass through the nonzero exit status that would trigger.

Comment: I don't know but maybe for now this is the most readable solution.

Answer (score 0):

This job is more suitable for `awk` than `sed`.

You may use this much more readable solution:

```bash
awk -v newver='18.0' '
BEGIN{FS=OFS="="}
$1 == "version" {
   $2 = newver
   ver = 1
}
1
END {
   if (!ver)
      print "version", newver
}' file

one_variable=/tmp
version=18.0
another_variable=jack
```

If you want to save changes in the same file then there are 2 ways:

1. For `gnu awk` use `-i inplace`

```bash
awk -i inplace -v newver='18.0' 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="="} $1 == "version" {$2 = newver; ver=1} 1; ENDFILE { if (!ver) print "version", newver }' file
```

2. For non-gnu awk use:

```bash
awk -v newver='18.0' 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="="} $1 == "version" {$2 = newver; ver=1} 1; END { if (!ver) print "version", newver }' file > _tmp &&
my _tmp file
```

Comment: Thanks but I'm looking for 1-line command working for both Linux and MacOS.

Comment: It is one line command only as I have shown towards end of my answer. Use non-gnu solution for that. I broke it into multiple lines earlier for readability purpose.

Answer (score 0):

When you don't care where the line with the version is, you can add new version at the end of the file and remove other version lines (if any).
Two commands with the same result, but not tested on Mac:

```
sed -ni '$ s/$/\nversion='"${version_selected}"'/;/^version=/!p;' infile
sed -i '/^version=/d; $ s/$/\nversion='"${version_selected}"'/' infile
```

With `awk`, without the `-i inplace`, you can use

```
file=$(mktemp)
awk -v v="${version_selected}" '
  /^version=/ {next}
  1;
  END {print "version=" v}' infile > "${file}" && mv "${file}" infile
```